# Android: use a datepicker and timepicker from within a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

I am facing a problem I do not know how to solve.

I have an activity, when I click on a particular item of the menu linked to this activity, a dialog is displayed and used to add an item. This item has a date and a time, but I do not manage to have a `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` within this dialog. I also try passing the activity to the dialog and use this one to display the `DatePicker,` but that does not work.
Before this, I handled the creation of such items within another Activity. In this case, it works fine. But I found the Dialog sexier... :-)
Would you have any ideas ?
Hope I am not too confused.....
thanks a lot,

I edit this post to share the code I have difficulties with.

I have a basic `Dialog` class that tried to use `DatePicker` and `TimePicker.` Basically, `Eclipse` complains that:

- the `showDialog` is undefined for `View.OnClickListener()`
- `onCreateDialog` method: The method `onCreateDialog(int)` of type `EventCreateDialog` must override or implement a super-type method
- `DatePickerDialog` is undefined (as this is not an activity)

All this stuff works from within an Activity but I cannot have it working from a Dialog.

Thanks a lot,

package com.android.myapp;

```
public class TestDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private Button mPickTime;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    private int mHour;
    private int mMinute;
    private Button mButton_ok;
    private Button mButton_ko;

    private ReadyListener readyListener;

    private Context context;
    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    public TestDialog(Context context, ReadyListener readyListener) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.readyListener = readyListener;
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_create);

        mButton_ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        mButton_ko = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ko);

        // Add listeners
        mButton_ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        mButton_ko.setOnClickListener(this);

        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);
        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        // get the current date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                        .append(mDay).append("-")
                        .append(mYear).append(" ")
                        .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                        .append(pad(mMinute)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mButton_ok) {
            // Do stuff....
        }
        if (v == mButton_ko) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    public interface ReadyListener {
        public void ready(MyObj myObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share the code that doesn't seem to be working?  I've used DatePicker and TimePicker within dialogs before with no problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry (I did not see I get a reply).
I will share the code, but just one question, which context do you provide to DatePicker and TimePicker when you call them from a dialog ? 
thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: Could you please share how this was resolved.

I am having the same prob.

How do we display a TimePicker (or some other dialog) on a button click from within a custom dialog? i.e. a dialog from within another dialog?

Comment: hi, well
it did not get resolved, I handle this
differently (in a view rather than in a dialog...)

Comment: Hmm... I too have this in a separate activity right now and everything works fine. However when I tried moving this to a Dialog (extending Dialog) was no longer able to get this to work.  :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have that works:

```
public class EditRecordDialog extends Dialog {
  protected Context _context;
  private   Record  _record;

  public EditRecordDialog( Context context,
                           Record  record ) {
    super( context );
    _context = context;
    _record  = record
    Button buttonDate;
    buttonDate.setText( _record.getRecordDate() ); // returns 'mm-dd-yy'

  } // EditRecordDialog


// showDatePickerDialog ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
private void showDatePickerDialog( View view ) {
  String dateString;
  int    year, month, day;

  dateString = buttonDate.getText().toString();
  month = Integer.valueOf( dateString.substring( 0, 2 ) ) - 1; // month is zero based
  day   = Integer.valueOf( dateString.substring( 3, 5 ) );
  year  = Integer.valueOf( "20" + dateString.substring( 6, 8 ) );

  DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog( _context, dateSetListener, year, month, day );
  dpd.show();

} // showDatePickerDialog ----------------------------------------------------


// OnDateSetListener +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override public void onDateSet( DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day ) {
    buttonDate.setText( ConfigObjectDAO.formatDate( (month+1) + "-" + day + "-" + year ) );
  } // onDateSet
}; // OnDateSetListener ------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PickerViewSample.java

```
package com.sai.samples.views;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class PickerViewSample extends Activity {

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;
    private TextView dateDisplay;
    private Button pickDate;
    private int year, month, day;
    private TextView timeDisplay;
    private Button pickTime;
    private int hours, min;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        pickDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        pickDate.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }

        });

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDate();

        timeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        pickTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);

        pickTime.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

        hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        updateTime();
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        timeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(min));

    }

    private void updateDate() {
        dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append('-')
                .append(month + 1).append('-').append(year));

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = 
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                year = yr;
                month = monthOfYear;
                day = dayOfMonth;
                updateDate();
            }
    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = 
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hours = hourOfDay;
                min = minute;
                updateTime();
            }

    };
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, year, month, day);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeListener, hours, min, false);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView android:text="@string/date_text" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="26px" 
    android:typeface="sans"></TextView>
<Button android:text="@string/date_button" 
    android:id="@+id/Button01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

<TextView android:text="@string/time_text" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26px" 
    android:typeface="sans"></TextView>
<Button android:text="@string/time_button" 
    android:id="@+id/Button02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

datepickerlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<DatePicker 
    android:id="@+id/DatePicker01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer is for an Activity.  He specifically said 'Dialog'. :(

Answer (score 1):

declare variables in global as:

```
private int year, month, day, Hour, Minute;

public static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;
```

in onCreate()

```
// Get current date by calender
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

call datepicker from button click

```
showDialog(Constant.DATE_PICKER_ID);
```

methods:

```
  @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case Constant.DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog.
            // set date picker for current date
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month, day);

        case Constant.TIME_PICKER_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, Hour, Minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;







            text_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("/").append(day).append("/").append(year)
                    .append(" "));


    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) { context.showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); }
            });
```

onCreateDialog can only be called from within an activity

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my own App to create a DatePicker in a dialog:

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_datepicker);
DatePicker datePicker = dialog1.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
datePicker.init(Integer.valueOf(date.substring(0, 4)), Integer.valueOf(date.substring(5, 7)) - 1, Integer.valueOf(date.substring(8, 10)), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        //do you stuff here 
    }
});
dialog1.show();
```